# Longest Fibonacci word

Tags: mathematics, optimization, sequence, algorithm

Fibonacci words are defined as $F_0 = a, F_1 = b, F_{n+2} = F_nF_{n+1}$ where $a, b$ are letters. How can you find the longest Fibonacci sub-word in a given string?
Try to solve it in linear time ($O(n)$).

Example: in a string: `BCBAABACB` the longest Fibonacci sub-word is `BAABA`

Comment: To be clear, are you requesting an algorithm here to solve a general problem?

Comment: It seems like it…

Comment: Isn't it about algorithms here also?

Comment: It's more about clever thinking than straightforward problems. This falls squarely in the latter category.

Comment: @Someone The two are not necessarily mutually exclusive. Devising an algorithm subject to a complexity constraint often requires considerable creativity.

Comment: If the problem is not your own invention you should give some reference. I found it for example here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29323/fibonacci-words